# Rails - Uploading large files directly to S3 with Jquery File Upload (hosted on Heroku )

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Heroku, which means I have to upload *multiple* large files to S3 directly.. I'm using Rails 3.2.11, and Ruby 1.9.3.  I do not wish to use carrierwave or paperclip gems, or really change much at this point - I just need to get this what I have working.

Before trying to move to S3, if I ran my app locally,  I could upload multiple large files to the local file system.   When  I ran it  on Heroku, small files upload but large ones failed. Hence the switch to S3..

I tried several tweaks, and also this link below, but it's just too much of a change to what I have that *already* working with the local server's file system (and Heroku as well, but Heroku just can't handle large files ..)

Tried:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

I've tried some of the other examples here on Stack Overflow but they are too much of a change for what works locally, and well, I don't grasp everything they are doing.

Now, what happens when I do try to upload images?

It's as if the file upload works - the preview images are successfully created, but nothing is ever uploaded to Amazon s3, and I don't receive any kind of error messages (like s3 authentication failure or anything.. nothing)

What do I need to change in order to get the files over to my s3 storage, and what can I write out to console to detect problems, if any, connecting to my s3?

My form:

```
        <%= form_for @status  do |f| %>

        {A FEW HTML FIELDS USED FOR A DESCRIPTION OF THE FILES - NOT IMPORTANT FOR THE QUESTION}

        File:<input id="fileupload"  multiple="multiple"  name="image" 
            type="file"  data-form-data = <%= @s3_direct_post.fields%> 
            data-url= <%= @s3_direct_post.url %> 
            data-host =<%=URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host%> >   
        <%= link_to 'submit', "#", :id=>'submit' , :remote=>true%>

        <% end %>
```

My jquery is:

```
....
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
      formData: {
                 batch: createUUID(),
                  authenticity_token:$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
      dataType: 'json',
      acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
              maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
              previewMaxWidth: 400,
              previewMaxHeight: 400,
              previewCrop: true,
      add: function (e, data) {

      tmpImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(data.files[0]) ; // create image preview 
      $('#'+ fn + '_inner' ).append(tmpImg);

    ...
```

My controller:

```
def index
#it's in the index just to simplify getting it working 

 @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')

end
```

The element that is generated for the form is (via Inspect Element):

```
        <input id="fileupload" multiple="multiple" name="image" 
    data-form-data="{&quot;key&quot;=>&quot;uploads/34a64607-8d1b-4704-806b-159ecc47745e/${filename}&quot;," &quot;success_action_status&quot;="
    >&quot;201&quot;," &quot;acl&quot;=">&quot;public-read&quot;," &quot;policy&quot;=">&quot;[encryped stuff - no need to post]&quot;,"
     &quot;x-amz-credential&quot;=">&quot;
[AWS access key]/[some number]/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&quot;
," &quot;x-amz-algorithm&quot;=">&quot;AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&quot;
," &quot;x-amz-date&quot;=">&quot;20150924T234656Z&quot;
," &quot;x-amz-signature&quot;=">&quot;[some encrypted stuff]&quot;}"
data-url="https://nunyabizness.s3.amazonaws.com" data-host="nunyabizness.s3.amazonaws.com" type="file">
```

Help!

Answer (score 2):

With S3 there actually is no easy out of the box solutions to upload files, because Amazon is a rather complex instrument.

I had a similar issue back in the day and spend two weeks trying to figure out how S3 works, and now use a working solution for uploading files onto S3. I can tell you a solution that works for me, I never tried the one proposed by Heroku.
A plugin of choice I use is Plupload, since it is the only component I actually managed to get working, apart from simple direct S3 uploads via XHR, and offers the use of percentage indicators and in-browser image resizing, which I find completely mandatory for production applications, where some users have 20mb images that they want to upload as their avatar.

Some basics in S3:

**Step 1**

Amazon bucket needs correct configuration in its CORS file to allow external uploads in the first place. The Heroku totorial already told you how to put the configuration in the right place.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

**Step 2**

Policy data is needed, otherwise your client will not be able to access the corresponding bucket file. I find generating policies to be better done via Ajax calls, so that, for example, admin gets the ability to upload files into the folders of different users.
In my example, cancan is used to manage security for the given user and figaro is used to manage ENV variables.

```
def aws_policy_image
  user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  authorize! :upload_image, current_user
  options = {}
  bucket = Rails.configuration.bucket
  access_key_id = ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
  secret_access_key = ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
  options[:key] ||= "users/" + params[:user_id] # folder on AWS to store file in
  options[:acl] ||= 'private'
  options[:expiration_date] ||= 10.hours.from_now.utc.iso8601
  options[:max_filesize] ||= 10.megabytes
  options[:content_type] ||= 'image/' # Videos would be binary/octet-stream
  options[:filter_title] ||= 'Images'
  options[:filter_extentions] ||= 'jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp'
  policy = Base64.encode64(
    "{'expiration': '#{options[:expiration_date]}',
      'conditions': [
        {'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256'},
        {'bucket': '#{bucket}'},
        {'acl': '#{options[:acl]}'},
        {'success_action_status': '201'},
        ['content-length-range', 0, #{options[:max_filesize]}],
        ['starts-with', '$key', '#{options[:key]}'],
        ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', ''],
        ['starts-with', '$name', ''],
        ['starts-with', '$Filename', '']
      ]
    }").gsub(/\n|\r/, '')

  signature = Base64.encode64(
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
      OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'),
      secret_access_key, policy)).gsub("\n", "")
  render :json => {:access_key_id => access_key_id, :policy => policy, :signature => signature, :bucket => bucket}
end
```

I went as far as put this method into the application controller, although you could find a better place for it.
Path to this function should be put into the route, of course.

**Step 3**

Frontend, get plupload: http://www.plupload.com/ make some link to act as the upload button:

```
<a id="upload_button" href="#">Upload</a>
```

Make a script that configures the plupload initialization.

```
function Plupload(config_x, access_key_id, policy, signature, bucket) {
  var $this = this;
  $this.config = $.extend({
  key: 'error',
  acl: 'private',
  content_type: '',
  filter_title: 'Images',
  filter_extentions: 'jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp',
  select_button: "upload_button",
  multi_selection: true,
  callback: function (params) {
  },
  add_files_callback: function (up, files) {
  },
  complete_callback: function (params) {
  }
}, config_x);
$this.params = {
  runtimes: 'html5',
  browse_button: $this.config.select_button,
  max_file_size: $this.config.max_file_size,
  url: 'https://' + bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/',
  flash_swf_url: '/assets/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
  silverlight_xap_url: '/assets/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
  init: {
    FilesRemoved: function (up, files) {
      /*if (up.files.length < 1) {
       $('#' + config.select_button).fadeIn('slow');
       }*/
    }
  },
  multi_selection: $this.config.multi_selection,
  multipart: true,
  // resize: {width: 1000, height: 1000}, // currently causes "blob" problem
  multipart_params: {
    'acl': $this.config.acl,
    'Content-Type': $this.config.content_type,
    'success_action_status': '201',
    'AWSAccessKeyId': access_key_id,
    'x-amz-server-side-encryption': "AES256",
    'policy': policy,
    'signature': signature
  },
// Resize images on clientside if we can
  resize: {
    preserve_headers: false, // (!)
    width: 1200,
    height: 1200,
    quality: 70
  },
  filters: [
    {
      title: $this.config.filter_title,
      extensions: $this.config.filter_extentions
    }
  ],
  file_data_name: 'file'
};
$this.uploader = new plupload.Uploader($this.params);
$this.uploader.init();

$this.uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function (up, file) {
  $('#' + file.id + ' .percent').text(file.percent + '%');
});

// before upload
$this.uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function (up, file) {
  // optional: regen the filename, otherwise the user will upload image.jpg that will overwrite each other
  var extension = file.name.split('.').pop();
  var file_name = extension + "_" + (+new Date);
  up.settings.multipart_params.key = $this.config.key + '/' + file_name + '.' + extension;
  up.settings.multipart_params.Filename = $this.config.key + '/' + file_name + '.' + extension;
  file.name = file_name + '.' + extension;
});

// shows error object in the browser console (for now)
$this.uploader.bind('Error', function (up, error) {
  console.log('Expand the error object below to see the error. Use WireShark to debug.');
  alert_x(".validation-error", error.message);
});

// files added
$this.uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
  $this.config.add_files_callback(up, files, $this.uploader);
  // p(uploader);
  // uploader.start();
});

// when file gets uploaded
$this.uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file) {
  $this.config.callback(file);
  up.refresh();
});

// when all files are uploaded
$this.uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function (up, file) {
  $this.config.complete_callback(file);
  up.refresh();
});
}
Plupload.prototype.init = function () {
  //
}
```

**Step 4**

The implemetation of the general multi-purpose file uploader function:

```
ImageUploader = {
  init: function (user_id, config, callback) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "/aws_policy_image",
      data: {user_id: user_id},
      error: function (request, status, error) {
      alert(request.responseText);
    },
    success: function (msg) {
      // set aws credentials
      callback(config, msg);
    }
  });
},
},
// local functions
photo_uploader: function (user_id) {
  var container = "#photos .unverified_images" // for example;
  var can_render = false;
  this.init(user_id,
    {
      select_button: "upload_photos",
      callback: function (file) {
        file.aws_id = file.id;
        file.id = "0";
        file.album_title = "userpics"; // I use this param to manage photo directory
        file.user_id = user_id;
        //console.log(file);
        [** your ajax code here that saves the image object in the database via file variable you get here **]
      });
    },
    add_files_callback: function (up, files, uploader) {
      $.each(files, function (index, value) {
        // do something like adding a progress bar html
      });
      uploader.start();
    },
    complete_callback: function (files) {
      can_render = true;
    }
  }, function (config, msg) {
    config.key = "users/" + user_id;
    // Most important part:
    window.photo_uploader = new Plupload(config, msg.access_key_id, msg.policy, msg.signature, msg.bucket);
  });
}
```

`can_render` variable is useful so that you can make the application only then re-render the page, when the uploader is actually done.

And to make the button work from somewhere else call:

```
ImageUploader.photo_uploader(user_id);
```

And the button will act as a Plupload uploader button.
What is important is that Policy is made in a way so that noone can upload the photo into someone else's directory.
It would be great to have a version that does the same not via ajax callbacks, but with web hooks, this is something I want to do in the future.

Again, this is not a perfect solution, but something that works good enough from my experience for the purpose of uploading images and videos onto amazon.

**Note** in case someone asks why I have this complex object-oriented structure of uploader objects, the reason is that my application has all different kinds of uploaders that behave differently and they need to have an initializer with common behavior. The way I did it I can write an initializer for, say, videos, with minimum amount of code, that will do similar things to the existing image uploader.

Comment: cool.. not sure it helps me but it I will look into this.. thanks so much, and I like your object oriented solution..